# How to sync calendar with GNOME without letting it to access dozen of other services?

Tags: gnome, 18.04, google, calendar

I want to sync calendar (located on top-bar on Ubuntu 18.04) with Google Calendar. In order to do that, I need to add Google to `Online Accounts` in system settings. When I log in, I'm informed that I need to give GNOME access to my mail, Google Drive, my photos&videos, contacts etc.

Is there any way I could give it access to calendar only?
[image]

Comment: After you allow access from this screen you should be able to enable/disable services individually from *Settings* > *Online Accounts*.

Comment: I'm asking this question due to privacy concerns. This doesn't solve a problem if I disable services on GNOME side, because how do I know whether GNOME will work as I told it to?

Comment: Shame that nobody has answered this question yet. It should just be the matter of creating an application token yourself and place it in a folder somewhere...